# Recent CSS AND/OR Jquery Cheat sheets?

Tags: jquery, css

Hey guys, I'm trying to find a complete cheat sheet that has the newest CSS3, along with the 1 and 2 spec.

I'm also trying to find a jQuery cheat sheet that's for 1.5.1, which is the newest. I googled, but only found old cheat sheets.

Thanks!

Comment: https://ohmycheatsheet.com or https://htmlcheatsheet.com could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CSS3 Cheat Sheet](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/css3-cheat-sheet/css3-cheat-sheet.pdf)

[jQuery Cheat Sheet - Within .zip](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/offlinelearning1.5/jqlearningkit.zip)

Answer (score 2):

This CSS cheat sheet is relatively old (it has everything up to 2.1), but it is particularly nice: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/css-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 2):

Smashing Magazine (with the help of [Veign.com](http://veign.com)) provides a [nice CSS 3 cheat sheet](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/images/css3-cheat-sheet/css3-cheat-sheet.pdf).  As for jQuery, I'll keep this thread current and share a link to two good jQuery 1.7 cheat sheets.  The second one is nice because it shows a star beside new or changed language features:

- [FutureColors.ru jQuery 1.7 cheat sheet](http://www.futurecolors.ru/jquery/) (HTML and PDF versions)
- [Woorkup.com jQuery 1.7 visual cheat sheet](http://woorkup.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/jQuery-17-Visual-Cheat-Sheet1.pdf) (PDF)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good [Qjuery Sheet Sheet](http://www.allwebcoding.com/cheat-sheet/5-best-reliable-jquery-cheat-sheet-web-design-and-development/) Collection.